# How to build OpenJDK with no interpter and no jit

Tags: java, llvm, zero, aot

I am developing an AOT compiler for java based on Java 7 so no invoke dynamic involved in Java standard API I am at the phase of generating LLVM IR code, but now I have to choose a runtime.

The runtime handles things like managing threads and monitors, object allocation garbage collector and so on. Therefore, I need a runtime with no interpreter or JIT. I found Android runtime, and tried to port it to linux, but it seems that he included an interpreter and he load classes from Dexcache, so no I am trying building a custom open jdk version.

I found iced tea which came with the project zero issue from the openjdk project but zero include interpreter.

Is there a way to build zero with no interpreter?

Comment: Short answer: you will have to code and build your own runtime.  Probably from scratch.  The OpenJDK and Android codebases are is designed on the assumption that there is an interpreter.

Comment: Shorter answer: good luck.

Comment: You might be able to salvage something useful from the old GCJ codebase, but that project never managed to produce a "complete" Java, and is now effectively dead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java

Comment: The problems is that gcj  is not compatible with open jdk this project is came to end

Comment: I know that.  However, you still might be able to salvage some code that might be useful.  If not, then you will probably need to write the whole lot from scratch!   Seriously, this is one of those situations where you / your supervisor *should have* worked out what you were going to do about a runtime *before* you invested lost of effort in the code generator.   Hence the "good luck" comment above.